# Cygwin gcc cannot find stdio.h

Tags: gcc, cygwin

I have a 64 bit Cygwin on my 64 bit Win7.
I installed gcc-core and gcc-g++ packages.
I made a simple C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  exit(0);
}
```

when I compile with: `gcc-c test.c` I got:
`fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory`

Doing it with `-v` flag I see:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include-fixed
 /usr/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../lib/../include/w32api
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.3 (x86_64-pc-cygwin)
```

The `stdio.h` which comes with gcc-core package is present on my pc at this location (which is fine according to Cygwin's package searcher also):
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/include/ssp/stdio.h`

What it means that `ssp` directory and why `stdio.h` is placed there ?
Why gcc cannot find `stdio.h` present at this location ?

Comment: I presume your actual source file has `#include <stdio.h>`, not `#include &lt;stdio.h&gt;`. I've fixed your question's formatting; please verify that it's still accurate. And `exit` requires `#include <stdlib.h>`, though that's not the cause of your problem.

Comment: You should add an include directory as Wumpus Q. Wumbley pointed out: this is not the file you want.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: you're right, I did the mistake while I edited the post

Comment: Meantime I did a Cygwin install on another machine and gcc worked fine. As Wumpus Q said I saw there a `/usr/include/stdio.h` which is missing on my machine. I also dont have string.h and stdlib.h in `/usr/include/` on my machine. So something went corrupted while cygwin-devel was installed ??? The cygwin-setup reports cygwin-devel package as installed (Keep) however I have 85 files in /usr/include/ in my machine compared to 112 which I have on the other machine where works

Comment: Yes : ` cygcheck -c cygwin-devel
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
cygwin-devel         1.7.33-1       Incomplete
`

Comment: click on "Keep" until it says "Reinstall" and then finish the setup and see if that fixes it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you found in the `ssp` directory is not a version of `<stdio.h>`. It only contains extra information about some of the functions in `<stdio.h>` for the stack-smash protector feature in gcc.

The actual `<stdio.h>` should be in `/usr/include`.

<s>This line in your `-v` output is very interesting:</s>

```
/usr/inlude
```

How did you get a `/usr/inlude` with no `c`?

Oops, the missing `c` in `inlude` was deleted in the edit by Keith Thompson.

So your gcc should be finding `/usr/include/stdio.h` if you have it. Is it there? As far as I can tell from the package file lists, it's supposed to be part of the cygwin base system (i.e. even if you haven't installed the compiler it should be there).

Are you missing any other header files? `<stdlib.h>` and `<string.h>` are good test candidates.

Here are some commands to investigate the cygwin package and whether it contains the file:

```
cygcheck -f /usr/include/stdio.h
cygcheck -c cygwin
cygcheck -l cygwin | grep stdio
```

**UPDATE:** so it seems I'm behind the times and there's a `cygwin-devel` package now. The header files aren't in the base `cygwin` package any more. To check the correct package on the latest cygwin, you'd use

```
cygcheck -c cygwin-devel
```

as has already been done in the comments. And since it's listed as "incomplete" the solution is probably to reinstall it using cygwin's setup program.